# Android mount system in write mode

Tags: android, root, mount

I have a android iso inside virtual box. 
I need to mount the /system in write mode.
It looks as if I am the root user, but when I try to mount it gived permission denied.

Below are the command outputs.

```
My shell:

root@eeepc:/ #


root@eeepc:/ # whoami
root


root@eeepc:/ # mount
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sys /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs / tmpfs ro,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda1 /mnt ext3 rw,relatime,errors=continue,barrier=0,data=writeback 0 0
/dev/loop0 /sfs squashfs ro,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop1 /system ext4 ro,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
tmpfs /cache tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda1 /data ext3 rw,relatime,errors=continue,barrier=0,data=writeback 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
```

**Command that i tried to remount:**

```
mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/loop1 /system
mount -o rw,remount -t ext4 /dev/loop1 /system
```

All of the above gave permission denied.

Any help ?

Comment: Have you tried 'adb remount' assuming you have adb working (you can likely connect adb via tcp)

Comment: @ChrisStratton : While running adb remount , i m having permission denied. As info : I used adb connect 127.0.0.1, to connect to virtual box device

Comment: If 'adb remount' (as distinct from the commands you posted above) is failing you should probably take that up with whoever provided the image.  However, another option you have is to mount the image as an auxiliary partition to a different VM which understands ext4 - for example, an ordinary (non-android) linux image - and make your change from that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton This looks tough to me, will try some thing, will be better if some links can be provided.... Thanks for help

Comment: Speaking of providing links, how about one to where you got the image?  Have you perused the discussion lists for whatever android-on-x86 distro this is?

Comment: This was the link : http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2011/09/ultra-fast-android-emulator/   . I have added a comment, lets see. Although I am still trying other ways

Comment: You should probably follow the chain to the project he says he got it from.  Also http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html says there's now an official x86 VM solution for fast emulation which you might look into.

Comment: That I have tried, but will try adb remount, with that also....

Comment: see http://dev.blogs.nuxeo.com/2011/10/speeding-up-the-android-emulator.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was not able to do this, but I installed android-x86-2.3 iso , and it's working now.

Now I am having problem of orientation, it is only working on landscape..

Hope I find some solution

Answer (score 2):

An ISO is based upon a write only file system, `ISO9660` does not have the concept of write once it is committed. Think of trying to change a file on a CD or DVD.

If you want to change a file in the /system then you need to approach the problem differently.

The /system mount point is a  loop mount to (probably) a file. You can either use a shadow file system over the top of it (good luck, casper etc.) or copy  its contents to another file system and toy with them there.

e.g. loop mount an file formatted to ext2

[first hit on google](http://blog.mmassonnet.info/2009/05/making-use-of-loop-devices-on-linux.html%5d)

[First hit on bing:](http://www.slax.org/documentation_loop_mount.php)

Comment: Its actually a .ova file(virtualbox file), that I imported directly, don't know how was it created. Sorry for missing this info...